# Using a frequency column to create a percentage column for multiple categories

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R but am struggling to create percentages from my column of frequencies

```
 Species   Year   State   Disease.status  F
1 Hedgehog 1870     L       Negative      7
2 Hedgehog 1870     L       Positive      17
3   Badger 1990     K       Positive      8
4 Blue Tit 1991     P       Negative      5
```

I want to code to create a data frame which creates a percentage from the "F" column which gives the percentage of species in a year, in that state that produced positive results in "Disease.status" instead of negative. Am new to R and any help would be appreciated.

The table below is what I'd like to produce from the table above.

```
 Species   Year   State     F%
1 Hedgehog 1870     L       29
2   Badger 1990     K       100
3 Blue Tit 1991     P       0
```

Comment: Can you please post expected output? It's hard to understand what you want to achieve

Comment: Is that helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You can `spread` the Disease.status column into wide format and then calculate, which is probably my preferred method.

```
df <- data.frame(Species = c("Hedgehog", "Hedgehog", "Badger", "Blue Tit"), State = c("L", "L", "K", "P"), Disease.status = c("Negative", "Positive",  "Positive", "Negative"), F = c(7, 17, 8, 5))

new_df <- df %>%
    spread(Disease.status, F) %>%
    mutate(Negative = ifelse(is.na(Negative), 0, Negative),
           Positive = ifelse(is.na(Positive), 0, Positive),
           F_pcent = Negative/(Negative + Positive))

new_df

   Species State Negative Positive   F_pcent
1   Badger     K        0        8 1.0000000
2 Blue Tit     P        5        0 0.0000000
3 Hedgehog     L        7       17 0.2916667
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more `F_pcent = Negative/(Negative + Positive)` ? (so it fits the percents in the expected output)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
# read your data
d <- read.table(text="Species   Year   State   Disease.status  F
                Hedgehog 1870     L       Negative      7
                Hedgehog 1870     L       Positive      17
                Badger 1990     K       Positive      8
                BlueTit 1991     P       Negative      5", header=T)

library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
  group_by(Species, Year, State) %>% 
  summarise(total=sum(F),
        percent= round(sum(ifelse(Disease.status == "Positive",F/total,0))*100,1))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   Species, Year [?]
   Species  Year  State total percent
    <fctr> <int> <fctr> <int>   <dbl>
1   Badger  1990      K     8   100.0
2  BlueTit  1991      P     5     0.0
3 Hedgehog  1870      L    24    70.8
```

The idea is to group the data, then calcualte the total number in each group using the summarise function. The result is cacluated using `ifelse` setting negatives to `zero` and summing up the percentages. All in one using `tidyverse/dplyr`